# Operator inequality between the Heisenberg Hamiltonian and the total spin

Tags: condensed-matter, operators, quantum-spin, spin-models

Consider a collection of $N$ spin-1/2 particles (qubits) with total spin

$$\vec{S} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \vec{\sigma}_n$$

and a Heisenberg Hamiltonian

$$H = -J \sum_{\langle n,m\rangle} \vec{\sigma}_n \cdot \vec{\sigma}_m$$

where $\vec{\sigma}_n = (\sigma_n^x, \sigma_n^y, \sigma_n^z)$ are the Pauli spin matrices for the $n$th qubit and where $\sum_{\langle n,m\rangle}$ denotes a sum over nearest-neighbors on some graph.

**What operator inequalities are known for bounding the squared total spin $\vec{S}^2$ with the Heisenberg Hamiltonian $H$?**

We are especially interested in bounding $\vec{S}^2$ to be near its maximum value $\vec{S}_{\mathrm{max}}^2 = (N/2)(N/2+1)$.  We were able to show that

$$\vec{S}_{\mathrm{max}}^2 - \vec{S}^2 \le C \frac{H-E_0}{J}$$

where $E_0=-J\sum_{\langle n,m\rangle} I$ is the ferromagnetic ground-state energy and where $C=O(N^3)$ is a dimensionless constant.  In the case of a 1-dimensional spin chain with periodic boundary conditions, $E_0 = -JN$ and $C = N^3/48 + O(N^2)$.

Is this inequality or a stronger version already known in the literature?  References greatly appreciated.  We are familiar with the work of Bärwinkel et al. [1] (also [2-4]), which, in the cases we are interested in, is weaker than the inequality above.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0210458

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0108432

[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0203270

[4] https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0101228

Comment: There is a trivial bound $\mathbf{S}_\text{max}^2-\mathbf{S}^2\leq \mathbf{S}_\text{max}^2\sim O(N^2)$. However, your right-hand side is $O(N^3)$ because of $C$.

Comment: Right. To be clear: The bound above shows that very low energies imply nearly maximal spin.  For this to be non-trivial for a sequence of models with $N$ increasing, it must be that the energy is $O(1/N)$.  This is the case, for instance, for long-wavelength single-magnon states on a 1-D spin chain, for which the energy goes like $1/N^2$.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that point. Thanks! Is there a similar bound for an antiferromagnetic Heisenberg chain?

Comment: The above bound, expressed in terms of $H=-J\sum_{\langle n,m\rangle} \vec{\sigma}_n\cdot\vec{\sigma}_m$ and $E_0 = -J\sum_{\langle n,m\rangle} I$, actually doesn't depend on the sign of $J$ because the operator $(H-E_0)/J = \sum_{\langle n,m\rangle}[I-\vec{\sigma}_n\cdot\vec{\sigma}_m]>0$ is independent of $J$.  (I've edited to make this clearer.) Of course, when $J<0$, $E_0$ is the maximum energy of $H$ rather than minimum energy, but the stated operator inequality holds regardless.